# NullPointerException when evaluating a macro

Tags: clojure

I'm writing a macro to implement the `when` built-in macro, here is the code:

```
(defmacro when-valid
  "Macro that does a series of actions if the condition
    is true"
  [condition & actions]
  `(if ~condition (~cons 'do ~actions) nil))
```

But when I evaluate it like:

```
(when-valid (< 1 2) (println "hello") (println "dear"))
```

I get the output:

```
hello
dear
clojure-noob.core=> NullPointerException   
clojure-noob.core/eval17411
```

I should get `nil` instead of `NullPointerException`.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's see what happens in the macroexpansion phase:

```
(macroexpand '(when-valid (< 1 2) (println "hello") (println "dear")))
```

If we evaluate the above expression, we get this:

```
(if (< 1 2)
  (#function[clojure.core/cons--4331]
   (quote do)
   ((println "hello")
    (println "dear")))
  nil)
```

Your problem is right here:

```
((println "hello")
 (println "dear"))
```

When Clojure evaluates this code, it will see that `(println "hello")` is a list, so it will evaluate it, assume that the returned result is a function, and try to invoke that function. Of course, `(println "hello")` returns `nil,` so you get a `NullPointerException`.

Why is this happening? Let's take a closer look at what your macro is doing:

```
(defmacro when-valid
  "Macro that does a series of actions if the condition is true"
  [condition & actions]
  `(if ~condition
     (~cons 'do ~actions)
     nil))
```

This returns a list whose first two items are the `if` symbol and the `condition` expression, and whose last item is `nil`. So far, so good. But in the "then" clause, instead of getting a list consisting of the `do` symbol followed by the `actions` expressions, you get a list with these three items:

1. The `cons` *function* (not the symbol, because you use `~` to resolve `cons`
2. The expression `'do`, which expands to `(quote do)`
3. The `actions` expressions, *wrapped in a list* because you use unquote (`~`) instead of unquote-splice (`~@`)

What you really want is this:

```
(defmacro when-valid
  "Macro that does a series of actions if the condition is true"
  [condition & actions]
  `(if ~condition
     (do ~@actions)))
```

Since the "then" expression is still inside of the syntax-quote, the `do` symbol will be quoted properly. By using `~@`, you can expand the `actions` sequence into a list with `do` at the beginning, rather than leaving it wrapped as a sequence, which would cause the problem explained above. I also left off the final `nil`, because it's implied in an `if` expression with no "else" clause.